# Android Device Monitor keeps crashing - Cannot export my SQLite Database to view contents

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I have created an Android application with an SQLite database. Now I want to view the contents / or the data stored in my database. A few weeks ago I used to able to enter the Android Device Monitor, export the database to a file and view it used a third party program called 'My Database Browser'. Now when I try to open the Android Device Monitor, it crashes and displays the following error:

> An error has occurred. See the log file /Users/Mark/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/1498057715134.log.

Can anyone help me get around this, or explain a different way of exporting my SQLite database so I can view the data stored within my database?

Comment: Please post device monitor's log file contents

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Facebook Stetho library](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/). One of it's features is database inspection for Android apps.